# Error with function FromFile c#

Tags: c#, image

I'm trying to use a function (FromFile) from c#, but I have had a error and I don´t understand why.

Can someone help me?
The code is this.

```
var imageStream = new MemoryStream();

using (var i = Image.FromFile(@"c:\ProductImages\" + _ref))
{
    i.Save(imageStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}

byte[] encbuff = imageStream.ToArray();

string enc = Convert.ToBase64String(encbuff, 0, encbuff.Length);
```

[image: This is the error]

Comment: Post the error as text in the question, not as a screenshot where you cut off half the message. Also format your code!

Comment: can you paste full error message?

Comment: I think the screenshot is justified in this case (although it should need a text description aswell, yes)

Comment: @Jcl Absolutely not. Imagine the screenshot goes away, the question then becomes (even more) useless.

Comment: PLEASE POST FULL ERROR MESSAGE!!!

Comment: @DavidG that's why I said that a text description should be given aswell, but the error is a tooltip/underline red error, which may be worth checking on an image

Answer (score 1):

Check the `usings` on top of your `.cs` file... you are using some namespace `MediaTypeNames` (or that's your class' namespace) which has a class `Image`, so it's trying to use that, instead of `System.Drawing.Image`, which is what you are expecting.

So either use the fully qualified name:

```
using (var i = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"c:\ProductImages\" + _ref))
```

Or have something like this on top of the file:

```
using Image = System.Drawing.Image;
```